# How to perform data replication

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an `scl_tb` in which i have to update salary column.

But my question is, while am updating salary column data replication should happen in another table called `upd_tb` as below

```
SELECT * FROM scl_tb;

id  Name  salary 
-----------------
1    A      100  
2    B      200  
3    C      400  
4    D      700
```

Need output like below

```
SELECT * FROM up_tb;

SI_NO  id  Name  new_sal  old_sal  ind
----------------------------------------
 1      1   A      0        100     N
 2      1   A      150      100     U
 1      2   B      220      200     U
 2      2   B      0        220     N
 3      1   A      400      150     U
 1      3   C      410      400     U
```

How can we write it either `SQL statement` or using `TRIGGER`?

If both method or any one method also give solution.

Comment: Search for an AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER you will find many examples. Alternatively, you could use an audit policy.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Can we do this using Oracle SQL?

Comment: Yes you could, however, SQL cannot run by itself. That's why you have triggers, audit policies etc. What is your requirement? Do you want a SQL statement that you want to manually execute everytime there is a DML on the source table?

Comment: You will face an issue while calculating the `SI_NO` using trigger in concurrent update.

Comment: @Tejash Then how can we solve ```SI_NO``` issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have a problem in your data in the up_tb. In the second row the `old_sal` should be **0**. Because as if I understand correctly `old_sal` column contains the previous salaray of an employee or whatever. So the table should look as follows.

```
SI_NO  id  Name  new_sal  old_sal             ind
--------------------------------------------------
 1      1   A      0        100                N
 2      1   A      150       0 (not 100)       U
```

So the solution would be a simple row trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_table 
    AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON scl_tb 
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    CURSOR c_up_tb IS SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM up_tb ut WHERE ut.id = :NEW.id;
    v_cnt c_up_tb%rowtype;
    v_status up_tb.ind%type;
BEGIN
   v_status := 'U';

   IF inserting THEN
       v_status := 'N';
   END IF;

   OPEN  c_up_tb;
   FETCH c_up_tb INTO v_cnt;
   CLOSE c_up_tb; 

   INSERT INTO up_tb VALUES ( v_cnt.cnt+1, :NEW.id, :NEW.name, :NEW.salary, NVL(:OLD.salary, 0), v_status); 

END;
```

Comment: I expect `'U'` and `'N'` are for "Update" and "New", not "Up" and "dowN".